# Graph topology (OSM data)

Tags: graphhopper

I'm making some deep tests of Graphhopper and I wonder what the created graph (from osm data) topology looks like ? Especially, I wonder if it looks like this :

[First possible topology](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/220375graphtopology1.png)

or this :

[Second possible topology](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/980933graphtopology2.png)

In other words, are nodes linked only to their closest neighbors ? According to my testing, I have the feeling that it is not the case ... if I'm right, why this topology choice ?

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you start the MiniGraphUI (in the tools module) you can see the topology directly.

And yes, the default topology is according to your second image because GraphHopper is using [Contraction Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies), a speed up method. You can still traverse on the normal topology only using `graph.getBaseGraph()`

And if you completely disable CH you always get the normal topology and slower (but more flexible) queries.

Comment: did you remove the folder and reimport?